# shinyURL interaction with updateSelectInput

Tags: r, shiny

As part of my user interface, the user selects a set  of model parameters that reside at the bottom of a three level deep list structure.

On server side, I use

```
observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, 'level1', choices = attributes(model[[input$toplevel]]))
})

observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, 'level2', choices = attributes(model[[input$toplevel]][[input$level1]]))
})
```

with choices of level1, level2 set to NULL in ui selectInput section. This updates selection box to only appropriate attributes for previous choice of level above.

The saved long URL name does include selected level1 and level2 choices. But when used, always just uses the top of attribute list for two level deep top of top-level choices.

Is there a clever way around this? I assume it is some use of the `selected =` of selectInput, but I seem to be tripping around, unable to uncover correct syntax for what would be known as input$level1 and input$level2 on server side.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization of user inputs by **shinyURL** is performed by matching the names from the URL query string to the names in `input`. What happens in your app is that all `selectInput`s are simultaneously set by **shinyURL** at the beginning, but this change triggers the observers to execute, which reset the inputs to their default value.

You can circumvent this by rendering your 2nd and 3rd level inputs dynamically using the function `renderUI`. This will allow for a delayed initialization, as **shinyURL** waits with setting the inputs until they are available. Please see the example below for an illustration of this approach.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyURL)

data = list(
  A = list(
    a = as.list(1:3),
    b = as.list(4:6),
    c = as.list(7:9)
  ),
  B = list(
    d = as.list(1:3),
    e = as.list(4:6),
    f = as.list(7:9)
  )
)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Dynamic UI"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("toplevel", "Nested List", choices = names(data)),
         uiOutput("s1"),
         uiOutput("s2"),
         shinyURL.ui()
      ),

      mainPanel(
         h2("Selected level"),
         textOutput("selectedLevel")
      )
   )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  shinyURL.server()

  output$s1 = renderUI(selectInput("lvl1",
                                   label = NULL,
                                   choices = names(data[[input$toplevel]])))
  output$s2 = renderUI({
    req(input$lvl1)
    selectInput("lvl2",
                label = NULL,
                choices = data[[input$toplevel]][[input$lvl1]])
    })

  output$selectedLevel = renderText(
    paste(input$toplevel, input$lvl1, input$lvl2, sep = " > ")
    )
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

### Edit (24 February 2016)

The reason why the inputs which are rendered dynamically by `renderUI` and placed on different tabs are initialized only when the user switches to the tab containing the input is the following: the `outputUI` interface elements which render such inputs are *output* objects, and as such are by default disabled when they are hidden on the web page.

The solution is to set the `suspendWhenHidden = FALSE` option in a call to `outputOptions` for each of the corresponding `outputUI` elements.

I've uploaded the modified example provided by Ken O'Brien to https://gist.github.com/aoles/a68892717c0280647455. It can be run from R by

```
shiny::runGist("a68892717c0280647455")
```

Please note that I've introduced some small improvement to the original example:

- replaced calls to `attributes()` by `names()`
- added missing calls to `req()`
- added the `id` argument to `tabsetPanel`s to allow restoring them
- wrapped some common parts in `ui.R` and `server.R` into functions
- modified the code generating the matrix of inputs

Comment: Thanks. This works partially. My additional complication, not letting this be a complete solution just yet, is that I have conditionals on some of the 3 level deep model parameter selections (not always used - therefore choice not displayed.) With this solution, until user manually moves to tab where it is set, with conditionals right, model select gets NULL for 2 lower levels. Original `observe`s  handled that - but as you said, then overwrote in URL input set call.

Comment: I see, could you maybe share a minimal working example illustrating the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Will do. Give me a day so I can get stripped version. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for posting a detailed example, it was very helpful in pin pointing the issue. Please see the edit to my original answer for the solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm only about a month into R coding. So not only did you solve my problem, looks like you tidied up some of my clumsy coding. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

@aoles

My first answer here is my starting point with observes. While putting it together I noticed an interesting detail. The recalled URL -will- load level2 value for setting that used topLevel set to first value of attribute list. level3 still wrong.

Model in GetModelParams.r

```
model <- list()
#*********************************************************

#
model$savory$creamcheese$wheat$beta <- 1
model$savory$creamcheese$wheat$alpha <- 2
model$savory$creamcheese$wheat$gamma <- 3
#
model$savory$creamcheese$raisin$beta <- 4
model$savory$creamcheese$raisin$alpha <- 5
model$savory$creamcheese$raisin$gamma <- 6

#
model$savory$lox$poppy$beta <- 7
model$savory$lox$poppy$alpha <- 8
model$savory$lox$poppy$gamma <- 9

#
model$savory$lox$sesame$beta <- 8
model$savory$lox$sesame$alpha <- 7
model$savory$lox$sesame$gamma <- 6

#
model$savory$butter$poppy$beta <- 5
model$savory$butter$poppy$alpha <- 4
model$savory$butter$poppy$gamma <- 3

#
model$savory$butter$wheat$beta <- 2
model$savory$butter$wheat$alpha <- 1
model$savory$butter$wheat$gamma <- 1

#
model$salty$bacon$toasted$beta <- 2
model$salty$bacon$toasted$alpha <- 3
model$salty$bacon$toasted$gamma <- 4

#
model$salty$bacon$untoasted$beta <- 5
model$salty$bacon$untoasted$alpha <- 6
model$salty$bacon$untoasted$gamma <- 7

#
model$sweet$jelly$white$beta <- 6
model$sweet$jelly$white$alpha <- 5
model$sweet$jelly$white$gamma <- 4

#
model$sweet$jelly$muffin$beta <- 3
model$sweet$jelly$muffin$alpha <- 2
model$sweet$jelly$muffin$gamma <- 1

#
model$sweet$jam$white$beta <- 7
model$sweet$jam$white$alpha <- 11
model$sweet$jam$white$gamma <- 13

#
model$sweet$jam$muffin$beta <- 1
model$sweet$jam$muffin$alpha <- 3
model$sweet$jam$muffin$gamma <- 5
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyURL)
##############################
### ui.R #####################
##############################

source("GetModelParams.r")

topLevel <- attributes(model)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("URL conditional setting example"),

    sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("setup",
                     radioButtons(inputId = "nTraces",
                                  label = "multiple trace, single parameter variation ",
                                  choices = list("single trace" = 1, "2 traces" = 2, "3 traces" = 3, "4 traces" = 4)),
                     selectInput(inputId = "topLev1",
                                 label = "select top Level",
                                 choices = topLevel),
                     selectInput(inputId = "secondLev1",
                                 label = "select second level",
                                 choices = NULL),
                     selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev1",
                                 label = "select third level",
                                 choices = NULL),
                     numericInput(inputId = "area1",
                                  label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                  min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
                     sliderInput(inputId = "temp1",
                                 label = "Temperature (C)",
                                 min = 85, max = 125, value = 125, step = 5)
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 2",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '2' || input.nTraces == '3' || input.nTraces == '4'",
                         radioButtons(inputId = "parVary",
                                      label = "choose single parameter variation ",
                                      choices = list("model" = "model",  "area" = "area", "temperature" = "temp")
                                      ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev2",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             selectInput(inputId = "secondLev2",
                                         label = "select second level",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev2",
                                         label = "select third Level",
                                         choices = NULL)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area2",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp2",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 3",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '3' || input.nTraces == '4'",
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev3",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             selectInput(inputId = "secondLev3",
                                         label = "select second level",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev3",
                                         label = "select third level",
                                         choices = NULL)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area3",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp3",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 4",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '4'",
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev4",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             selectInput(inputId = "secondLev4",
                                         label = "select second level",
                                         choices = NULL),
                             selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev4",
                                         label = "select third level",
                                         choices = NULL)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area4",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp4",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
            ),
            shinyURL.ui(tinyURL = FALSE)
        )
    ),

    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Output and data type", tableOutput("textDisplay")),
            tabPanel("Model plots", plotOutput("modelPlot"))
        )
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyURL)
##########################################
##### server.R ###########################
##########################################

source("GetModelParams.r")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    shinyURL.server(session)
    modelCalc <- function(temp,area,model)
    {
        hrs <- seq(from =0, to = 2, by = 0.05)
        F <- area*(model$alpha) + hrs*(model$beta)^3 + exp(model$gamma*(temp/100)*hrs)
        list(F = F, hrs = hrs)
    }

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'thirdLev4', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev4]][[input$secondLev4]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'secondLev4', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev4]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'thirdLev3', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev3]][[input$secondLev3]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'secondLev3', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev3]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'thirdLev2', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev2]][[input$secondLev2]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'secondLev2', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev2]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'thirdLev1', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev1]][[input$secondLev1]]))
    })

    observe({
        updateSelectInput(session, 'secondLev1', choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev1]]))
    })

    output$modelPlot <- renderPlot({
        temp <- lapply(paste0("temp",1:as.numeric(input$nTraces)), function(x) input[[x]])

        area <- lapply(paste0("area",1:as.numeric(input$nTraces)), function(x) input[[x]])

        modelStr <- c("topLev", "secondLev", "thirdLev")
        modelCall <- lapply(1:as.numeric(input$nTraces), function(n) paste0(modelStr,n))
        modelIn <- lapply(modelCall,function(x) model[[input[[x[1]]]]][[input[[x[2]]]]][[input[[x[3]]]]])
        mLegendStr <- lapply(modelCall, function(x) paste(input[[x[1]]],input[[x[2]]],input[[x[3]]]))

        modelOut <- list()
        if(input$nTraces == '1')
        {
            modelOut <- modelCalc(area=area[[1]],temp=temp[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]])
        } else
        {
            modelOut <- switch(input$parVary,
                           "model" = lapply(modelIn,modelCalc,area=area[[1]],temp=temp[[1]]),
                           "temp" = lapply(temp,modelCalc,area=area[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]]),
                           "area" = lapply(area,modelCalc,temp=temp[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]])
                           )
        }

        if(input$nTraces =='1')
        {
            modelOut_flat <- unlist(modelOut)
        } else
        {
            modelOut_flat <- unlist(lapply(modelOut,unlist,recursive=FALSE))
        }
        colorVec <- c('red','blue','green','cyan','magenta','black')
        F_flat <- modelOut_flat[grep("^F",names(modelOut_flat))]
        hrs_flat <- modelOut_flat[grep("^hrs",names(modelOut_flat))]
        ylim_v <- range(F_flat[F_flat>0])
        xlim_h <- range(hrs_flat[hrs_flat>0])

        if(input$nTraces == '1')
        {
            plot(modelOut$hrs[modelOut$F>0],modelOut$F[modelOut$F>0],
                 log="xy",pch=1, col=colorVec[1],
                 xlab="Time [hrs]", ylab="Model output",'o',
                 ylim=ylim_v,xlim=xlim_h)
        } else
        {
            plot(modelOut[[1]]$hrs[modelOut[[1]]$F>0],modelOut[[1]]$F[modelOut[[1]]$F>0],
                 log="xy",pch=1, col=colorVec[1],
                 xlab="Time [hrs]",ylab="Model output",'o',
                 ylim=ylim_v,xlim=xlim_h)
        }
        grid(col="blue")
        if(input$nTraces != '1')
        {
            for(i in 2:length(modelOut)) {
                points(modelOut[[i]]$hrs[modelOut[[i]]$F>0],modelOut[[i]]$F[modelOut[[i]]$F>0],
                       pch=1,col=colorVec[i],'o')

            }
        }

        leg.names <- switch(input$parVary,
                            "temp" = sprintf('Temp=%.0f C',temp),
                            "area" = sprintf('Area=%.2e um^2',area),
                            "model"= sprintf('model=%s',mLegendStr)
                            )
        legend("topleft",leg.names,bg="white",pch=1,lty=1,col=colorVec)

        par(ps=11)
        titleRet <-  switch(input$parVary,
                            "temp" = title(sprintf("%s %s %s MODEL; Area=%.2eum^2", input$topLev1,input$secondLev1,input$thirdLev1,area[[1]])),
                            "area" = title(sprintf("%s %s %s MODEL; temp=%.0fC", input$topLev1,input$secondLev1,input$thirdLev1,temp[[1]])),
                            "model"= title(sprintf("MODEL; temp=%.0fC; Area=%.2eum^2", temp[[1]],area[[1]]))
                            )
    })

    output$textDisplay <- renderTable({
        getMat = matrix(c(input$nTraces, class(input$nTraces),
                          input$topLev1, class(input$topLev1),
                          input$secondLev1, class(input$secondLev1),
                          input$thirdLev1, class(input$thirdLev1),
                          input$temp1, class(input$temp1),
                          input$area1, class(input$area1),
                          input$topLev2, class(input$topLev2),
                          input$secondLev2, class(input$secondLev2),
                          input$thirdLev2, class(input$thirdLev2),
                          input$temp2, class(input$temp2),
                          input$area2, class(input$area2),
                          input$topLev3, class(input$topLev3),
                          input$secondLev3, class(input$secondLev3),
                          input$thirdLev3, class(input$thirdLev3),
                          input$temp3, class(input$temp3),
                          input$area3, class(input$area3),
                          input$parVary, class(input$parVary)
                          ), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
        colnames(getMat) = c("Value", "Class")
        getMat
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@aoles Second answer incorporates your suggestion. This basically works as URL recall -AFTER- user manually steps through setting to  "model" for parameter variation, then stepping through trace tabs. I was hoping for something that didn't require that manual effort.

Many Thanks for your attention.

Model parameter file same.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyURL)
##############################
### ui.R #####################
##############################

source("GetModelParams.r")

topLevel <- attributes(model)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("URL conditional setting example"),

    sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("setup",
                     radioButtons(inputId = "nTraces",
                                  label = "multiple trace, single parameter variation ",
                                  choices = list("single trace" = 1, "2 traces" = 2, "3 traces" = 3, "4 traces" = 4)),
                     selectInput(inputId = "topLev1",
                                 label = "select top Level",
                                 choices = topLevel),
                     uiOutput("sec1"),
                     uiOutput("thrd1"),
                     numericInput(inputId = "area1",
                                  label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                  min = 1, max = 10, value = 5),
                     sliderInput(inputId = "temp1",
                                 label = "Temperature (C)",
                                 min = 85, max = 125, value = 125, step = 5)
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 2",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '2' || input.nTraces == '3' || input.nTraces == '4'",
                         radioButtons(inputId = "parVary",
                                      label = "choose single parameter variation ",
                                      choices = list("model" = "model",  "area" = "area", "temperature" = "temp")
                                      ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev2",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             uiOutput("sec2"),
                             uiOutput("thrd2")
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area2",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp2",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 3",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '3' || input.nTraces == '4'",
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev3",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             uiOutput("sec3"),
                             uiOutput("thrd3")
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area3",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp3",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
                     ),
            tabPanel("trace 4",
                     conditionalPanel(
                         condition = "input.nTraces == '4'",
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'model'",
                             selectInput(inputId = "topLev4",
                                         label = "select top level",
                                         choices = topLevel),
                             uiOutput("sec4"),
                             uiOutput("thrd4")
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'area'",
                             numericInput(inputId = "area4",
                                          label = "Total gate area (um^2)",
                                          min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
                         ),
                         conditionalPanel(
                             condition = "input.parVary == 'temp'",
                             sliderInput(inputId = "temp4",
                                         label = "Temperature (C)",
                                         min = 85, max = 125, value = 0, step = 5)
                         )
                     )
            ),
            shinyURL.ui(tinyURL = FALSE)
        )
    ),

    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Output and data type", tableOutput("textDisplay")),
            tabPanel("Model plots", plotOutput("modelPlot"))
        )
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyURL)
##########################################
##### server.R ###########################
##########################################

source("GetModelParams.r")

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    shinyURL.server(session)
    modelCalc <- function(temp,area,model)
    {
        hrs <- seq(from =0, to = 2, by = 0.05)
        F <- area*(model$alpha) + hrs*(model$beta)^3 + exp(model$gamma*(temp/100)*hrs)
        list(F = F, hrs = hrs)
    }

    output$sec1 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "secondLev1",
                    label = "select second level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev1]])
                    )
    })

    output$thrd1 <- renderUI({
        req(input$secondLev1)
        selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev1",
                    label = "select third level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev1]][[input$secondLev1]])
                    )
    })

    output$sec2 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "secondLev2",
                    label = "select second level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev2]])
                    )
    })

    output$thrd2 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev2",
                    label = "select third level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev2]][[input$secondLev2]])
                    )
    })

    output$sec3 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "secondLev3",
                    label = "select second level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev3]])
                    )
    })

    output$thrd3 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev3",
                    label = "select third level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev3]][[input$secondLev3]])
                    )
    })

    output$sec4 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "secondLev4",
                    label = "select second level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev4]])
                    )
    })

    output$thrd4 <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "thirdLev4",
                    label = "select third level",
                    choices = attributes(model[[input$topLev4]][[input$secondLev4]])
                    )
    })

    output$modelPlot <- renderPlot({
        temp <- lapply(paste0("temp",1:as.numeric(input$nTraces)), function(x) input[[x]])

        area <- lapply(paste0("area",1:as.numeric(input$nTraces)), function(x) input[[x]])

        modelStr <- c("topLev", "secondLev", "thirdLev")
        modelCall <- lapply(1:as.numeric(input$nTraces), function(n) paste0(modelStr,n))
        modelIn <- lapply(modelCall,function(x) model[[input[[x[1]]]]][[input[[x[2]]]]][[input[[x[3]]]]])
        mLegendStr <- lapply(modelCall, function(x) paste(input[[x[1]]],input[[x[2]]],input[[x[3]]]))

        modelOut <- list()
        if(input$nTraces == '1')
        {
            modelOut <- modelCalc(area=area[[1]],temp=temp[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]])
        } else
        {
            modelOut <- switch(input$parVary,
                           "model" = lapply(modelIn,modelCalc,area=area[[1]],temp=temp[[1]]),
                           "temp" = lapply(temp,modelCalc,area=area[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]]),
                           "area" = lapply(area,modelCalc,temp=temp[[1]],model=modelIn[[1]])
                           )
        }

        if(input$nTraces =='1')
        {
            modelOut_flat <- unlist(modelOut)
        } else
        {
            modelOut_flat <- unlist(lapply(modelOut,unlist,recursive=FALSE))
        }
        colorVec <- c('red','blue','green','cyan','magenta','black')
        F_flat <- modelOut_flat[grep("^F",names(modelOut_flat))]
        hrs_flat <- modelOut_flat[grep("^hrs",names(modelOut_flat))]
        ylim_v <- range(F_flat[F_flat>0])
        xlim_h <- range(hrs_flat[hrs_flat>0])

        if(input$nTraces == '1')
        {
            plot(modelOut$hrs[modelOut$F>0],modelOut$F[modelOut$F>0],
                 log="xy",pch=1, col=colorVec[1],
                 xlab="Time [hrs]", ylab="Model output",'o',
                 ylim=ylim_v,xlim=xlim_h)
        } else
        {
            plot(modelOut[[1]]$hrs[modelOut[[1]]$F>0],modelOut[[1]]$F[modelOut[[1]]$F>0],
                 log="xy",pch=1, col=colorVec[1],
                 xlab="Time [hrs]",ylab="Model output",'o',
                 ylim=ylim_v,xlim=xlim_h)
        }
        grid(col="blue")
        if(input$nTraces != '1')
        {
            for(i in 2:length(modelOut)) {
                points(modelOut[[i]]$hrs[modelOut[[i]]$F>0],modelOut[[i]]$F[modelOut[[i]]$F>0],
                       pch=1,col=colorVec[i],'o')

            }
        }

        leg.names <- switch(input$parVary,
                            "temp" = sprintf('Temp=%.0f C',temp),
                            "area" = sprintf('Area=%.2e um^2',area),
                            "model"= sprintf('model=%s',mLegendStr)
                            )
        legend("topleft",leg.names,bg="white",pch=1,lty=1,col=colorVec)

        par(ps=11)
        titleRet <-  switch(input$parVary,
                            "temp" = title(sprintf("%s %s %s MODEL; Area=%.2eum^2", input$topLev1,input$secondLev1,input$thirdLev1,area[[1]])),
                            "area" = title(sprintf("%s %s %s MODEL; temp=%.0fC", input$topLev1,input$secondLev1,input$thirdLev1,temp[[1]])),
                            "model"= title(sprintf("MODEL; temp=%.0fC; Area=%.2eum^2", temp[[1]],area[[1]]))
                            )
    })

    output$textDisplay <- renderTable({
        getMat = matrix(c(input$nTraces, class(input$nTraces),
                          input$topLev1, class(input$topLev1),
                          input$secondLev1, class(input$secondLev1),
                          input$thirdLev1, class(input$thirdLev1),
                          input$temp1, class(input$temp1),
                          input$area1, class(input$area1),
                          input$topLev2, class(input$topLev2),
                          input$secondLev2, class(input$secondLev2),
                          input$thirdLev2, class(input$thirdLev2),
                          input$temp2, class(input$temp2),
                          input$area2, class(input$area2),
                          input$topLev3, class(input$topLev3),
                          input$secondLev3, class(input$secondLev3),
                          input$thirdLev3, class(input$thirdLev3),
                          input$temp3, class(input$temp3),
                          input$area3, class(input$area3),
                          input$parVary, class(input$parVary)
                          ), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
        colnames(getMat) = c("Value", "Class")
        getMat
    })
})
```